# If $A$ is similar to $B$, then $A$ is invertible $\implies$ B is invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I think that in order to achieve the invertibility, $\det(A)\ne 0$. But for similarity, we only have that $B=P^{-1}AP$ associates with. If we have $-1$ as power to both sides the equality would establish, but how do you prove the invertibility?

Comment: Can you explicitly write down an inverse for $P^{-1}AP$ given that $A$ is invertible?

Comment: $A$ is invertible $\Rightarrow$ $0$ is not an eigen value of $A$ $\Rightarrow$ $0$ is not an eigen value of $B$ $\Rightarrow$ $B$ is invertible.

Answer (score 6):

A, B similair $\implies$ there exists a matrix P such that $B = P^{-1}A P$

Now, using the fact that $det(P^{-1}) = \frac{1}{det(P)}$ and $det(AB) = det(A)det(B)$,

$det(B) = det( P^{-1}A P)= det(P^{-1})det(A)det(P) = det(A)$

Since A is invertible then $det(A) \neq 0$.

Thus B is invertible.

Comment: Great answer thanks

Answer (score 1):

The fact that $P^{-1}$, $A$, and $P$ are invertible means their product $P^{-1}AP$ is invertible.  Why is this true?  What is a candidate for the inverse of this matrix?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If $B=P^{-1}AP$, what is $B(P^{-1}A^{-1}P)$?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $A$ is similar to $B$ and $A$ is invertible. This implies there exists invertible matrix $P$ such that $B=P^{-1}AP $ and $AA^{-1}=A^{-1}A=I.$

Observe that

$B(P^{-1}A^{-1}P)=(P^{-1}AP)(P^{-1}A^{-1}P)=I$

and

$(P^{-1}A^{-1}P)B=(P^{-1}A^{-1}P)(P^{-1}AP)=I.$

Therefore $B$ is invertible and $B^{-1}=(P^{-1}A^{-1}P)$.

Comment: Just what I was looking for. Thank you!